# Syntax to output random slope estimate for nested random variable in SAS PROC GLIMMIX

Tags: nested, sas, random-effects

I wish to look at the fixed effects of three variables, PS, TH, and HW for the random variable ID. I am also interested in knowing the estimates for the random slope of each subject (ID) for each fixed effect. Some subjects had data from multiple years, so I have to nest year within ID. So far I have the following code for some preliminary analysis:

```
proc glimmix data=dat method=laplace;
   class year;
   class ID;
   model use = PS TH HW / dist=binomial link=logit solution;
   random intercept / subject = year(ID);
   random PS / subject = year(ID) solution;
   random TH / subject = year(ID) solution;
   random HW / subject = year(ID) solution;
  run;
```

When this code runs, I get random slope estimates for year(ID) for each fixed effect, e.g.,

```
Solution for Random Effects

                                            Std Err
Effect       Subject           Estimate        Pred       
PS           year (ID) 2 111      1.1714      0.7257     
TH           year (ID) 2 111      4.5081      1.2953    
HW           year (ID) 2 111     -1.3109      0.4196     
PS           year (ID) 4 114      0.5999      0.5608     
TH           year (ID) 4 114      4.7292      1.0664     
HW           year (ID) 4 114     -1.8526      0.3289
```

That's good, but I would also like to get the random slope estimates for **just** ID too. Ideally, the model would *account* for some IDs having more than one year, and give me a random slope estimate for year(ID) **AND** ID.

Question: How can I tell SAS to output a solution for just ID?

When I tried to run the following code to do just that, I got some weird blank spaces in my output for random effects, and the parameter estimates differed from the output I obtained with the above code. This code below seems overly complex - shouldn't the above code be able to to the job?

```
proc glimmix data=dat method=laplace;
   class year;
   class ID;
   model use = PS TH HW / dist=binomial link=logit solution;
   random intercept / subject = ID;
   random PS / subject = ID solution;
   random TH / subject = ID solution;
   random HW / subject = ID solution;
   random intercept / subject = year(ID);
   random PS / subject = year(ID) solution;
   random TH / subject = year(ID) solution;
   random HW / subject = year(ID) solution;
  run;

Example of part of the "Solutions for Random Effects" table

Effect       Subject           Estimate        Pred      
PS           ID 111              0.5587      1.4640     
TH           ID 111              4.2063      2.1891     
HW           ID 111             -0.9158      0.6462     
PS           Year(ID) 2 111      0.4944      1.4721    
PS                                    0      1.8627     
TH           Year(ID) 2 111      0.3569      1.7628     
TH                                    0      1.8037     
HW           Year(ID) 2 111     -0.3687      0.5800     
HW                                    0      0.5639     
PS           ID 114              0.2531      1.3999     
TH           ID 114              4.4162      2.0840     
HW           ID 114             -1.2981      0.6914     
PS           Year(ID) 4 114      0.2240      1.4027
```

*Note - all "pred" values within each fixed effect listed without a subject are the same.